# What Was Their Name That Person?

Tags: knowledge

My Stupid Cousin is at it again. (sigh)

He's trying to make a list of his all-time favorite celebrities and needs help. He seems only to remember *what they did,* not their names.

Here are his descriptions:

---

A. "There was this spooky guy back in the '60's who still had hot legs in the '80s."

B. "This other guy coached basketball in New Zealand, went to the big show, and came away with six Oscars."

C. "There was this one guy who was assassinated *twice* as president of the U.S., then, years later, he played in the Superbowl."

D. "There was this chick who married a millionaire, died, then came back to life(?) wearing god-awful makeup."

E. "I remember a tiny little cowboy with a drawl and a limp that sang rap songs about candy."

F. "There was an 80's 'Big Hair' rocker that sang ballads about TPS reports."

G. "A guy who was... um... a Hobbit? ...then fought fires in post 9/11 NYC."

H. "NYC undercover cop that was the grandmother of Wednesday and 'chased' money with her father."

---

Can you tell me his 17 favorite celebs?

Hint:

> Number of Persons to find: A:2✓ B:2✓ C:3✓ D:2✓ E:2✓ F:1✓ G:2 H:3✓

Hint #2:

> Hobbits (G.) might have worked in with the guy from New Zealand (B.).

Hint #3:

> The one who married a millionaire (D.) must've caught some kinda STD, she scratched for 7 years.

Comment: it seems like you have 8 hints but you ask for 17 celebs? Does each hint stand for only one celeb or more?

Answer (score 8):

Partial -

A. "There was this spooky guy back in the '60's who still had hot legs in the '80s."

> **Rod Serling** (The Twilight Zone host/narrator from 1959-1964)
> **Rod Stewart** (the song Hot Legs in 1977, not 1980s, though Tina Turner covered it in 1982)
> Apparently the legs were still hot

D. "There was this chick who married a millionaire, died, then came back to life(?) wearing god-awful makeup."

> **Marilyn Monroe** from How to Marry a Millionaire (1953) and, from the hint, The Seven Year Itch (1955)
> **Marilyn Manson**, a musical performer with a non-standard taste in makeup

E. "I remember a tiny little cowboy with a drawl and a limp that sang rap songs about candy."

> **John Wayne** and **Lil Wayne**

F. "There was an 80's 'Big Hair' rocker that sang ballads about TPS reports."

> **Michael** (or maybe Mike?) **Bolton**

H. "NYC undercover cop that was the grandmother of Wednesday and 'chased' money with her father."

> **Channing Tatum** played an undercover cop in 21 Jump Street (2012)
> **Carol Channing** voiced Grandmama Addams in 1992
> **Tatum O'Neal** perhaps, in Paper Moon with her dad, Ryan?

---

Probably wrong new guess
G. "A guy who was... um... a Hobbit? ...then fought fires in post 9/11 NYC."

> **Guillermo Del Toro** was a writer for The Hobbit movies
> **Guillermo Diaz** was on one episode of Third Watch

Comment: Right on both, I'm sure the legs were still pretty hot in the 80's. :)

Comment: @Chowzen I think that's highly debatable. =)   Added a long shot (like 8 miles long) for E.

Comment: [No debate!](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a3/a2/05/a3a20566ba85933fb04acae1cc0465d9.jpg) ...and no chance on E, though a good guess. Looking for (debatably) the most famous western movie star.

Comment: @Chowzen 1) wow 2) [this](https://img.memecdn.com/rod-do-you-think-im-sexy-stewart_o_1046595.jpg) is how I will always picture him 3) added a guess for H

Comment: H is good! only D and G  to go...

Comment: @Chowzen Sorry, forgot to continue this one.  Thanks for the reminder + hint.  D should be good to go, just mulling over G.

Comment: "D" works! For "G,"think of a bull that needs to be rescued?

Comment: @Chowzen Sorry, I feel like I'm letting you down on this one.  I'm aware of several hobbits and a handful of TV firefighters, but I can't find an overlap between any of them.  Your bull hint made me think of a person (added as a guess) and one of the two shows I was already stuck on.  And interestingly, H.3. was on Rescue Me.  I've added a guess to show you how far I've gone astray (and maybe get some more eyes on it).

Comment: No worries! The show from H3 is right, now coordinate with [a bull](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67827/what-was-their-name-that-person/67870#67870)

Answer (score 7):

Just dropping one in here so people understand how we're meant to solve it - here's C.

> Two assassinated US presidents; pick from Lincoln, Kennedy, Garfield
>  NFL player who appeared in a SB
>  [Lincoln Kennedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincoln_Kennedy)

Answer (score 6):

B. "This other guy coached basketball in New Zealand, went to the big show, and came away with six Oscars."

> Peter Jackson (director of the LOTR triology) and Phil Jackson (coach of the Chicago Bulls at their height)